# get - admin create order link and specify customer (for manual orders)

Tags: admin, customer, create-order

I want to generate a link to the sales create order page (manual order page) in the admin and submit a customer id so that it opens automatically with the customers details filled out in the address form.

```
  index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/key
```

I know sometimes a $this->getUrl('path') works but I can't find any instructions online for setting a customer before the page loads. A solution like the following would obviously be ideal.

```
 $this->getUrl('sales/order/create/', $customer_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your admin template or block file:

```
echo $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_create', array('customer_id' => 137));
```

This will land you on store selection page. If you already know store id you can add that as well:

```
echo $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_create', array('customer_id' => 137, 'store_id' => 1));
```

**EDIT**

Alternative method

```
echo $this->helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/sales_order_create', array('customer_id' => 137, 'store_id' => 1));
```

Comment: Nope. How does your url look like?

Comment: `http://mysite.localhost/shop/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/customer_id/74/store_id/1/` this just goes to the dashboard (i'm using the second option with store id but it happens with both)

Comment: `key` param is missing for some reason. Try with the snippet I just added. Url should look like `index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/customer_id/137/store_id/1/key/23c81d9......`

Comment: The bottom option works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$customer_id` is already the correct ID for the customer, I think you'd just need:

```
$this->getUrl('sales/order/create/', array('customer_id' => $customer_id));
```